# Stream Cipher proof of maximal period length for $n = 2^m$

Tags: stream-cipher

While reading *A course of Mathematical Cryptography* by Baumslag et al., I have trouble understanding parts of the proof of Theorem 2.3.3, namely the necessary condition :

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n=2^m,m\geq1$ and let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f:\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_n, x\to\overline{a}x+\overline{b}$ is a linear congruence generator. Further let $s\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ be given and $x_0=\overline{s},x_1=f(x_0),\dots.$ Then the sequence $x_0,x_1,\dots$ is periodic with the maximal period length $n=2^m$ if the following holds:

1. $a$ is odd.
2. If $m\geq2$ then $a\equiv1\mod{4}.$
3. $b$ is odd and $\overline{b}\neq\overline{0}.$

The proof goes as follow for $m\geq2$ and thus $n\geq 4$:

Assume (1), (2) and (3) are satisfied.We show that we obtain maximal period lenth $n = 2^m$ for $x_0=\overline{0}$ which proves the theorem.

Let $x_0=\overline{0}.$ We obtain recursively $$x_k = (\overline{1}+\overline{a}+\dots+\overline{a}^{k-1})\overline{b}$$ for $k\geq1.$ Since $b$ is odd we have
$$x_k=\overline{0}\iff(\overline{1}+\overline{a}+\dots+\overline{a}^{k-1})=\overline{0}.$$
We write $k = 2^rt$ with $r\geq0$ and $t$ odd. Then
$$\overline{0}=(\overline{1}+\overline{a}+\dots+\overline{a}^{k-1})=(\overline{1}+\overline{a}+\dots+\overline{a}^{2^r-1})(\overline{1}+\overline{a}^{2^r}+(\overline{a}^{2^r})^2+\dots+(\overline{a}^{2^r})^{t-1}).$$
The second factor is congruent to 1 modulo 2 and hence
$$2^m|(1+a+\dots+a^{k-1})\iff2^m|(1+a+\dots+a^{2^r-1}).$$

*The integer $1+a+\dots+a^{2^r-1}$ is divisible by $2^r$ since it is a sum of $2^r$ odd numbers but not divisible by $2^{r+1}.$ It follows that $r\geq m\iff2^m|k.$ Therefore $x_k=\overline{0}$ occurs for $k\geq1$ for the first time when $k=n=2^m$.*

I don't follow the very last part in italic (from "The integer..."). I will be glad if someone could enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite precise. Instead they should observe that the integer $1+a+\cdots+a^{2^r-1}$ is the sum of a geometric progression with $a\equiv1\pmod 4$ and so is divisible by $2^r$ but not $2^{r+1}$. To see this we write $a=1+2^su$ with $u$ odd and $s\ge2$ and see that
$$1+a+\cdots+a^{2^r}=\frac{a^{2^r}-1}{a-1}.$$
We then consider the numerator
$$a^{2^r}-1=(2^su+1)^{2^r}-1
=\left(1+2^r(2^su)+2^{r-1}(2^r-1)(2^{2s}u^2)+\cdots\right)$$
and
$$\left(1+2^r(2^su)+2^{r-1}(2^r-1)(2^{2s}u^2)+\cdots\right)\equiv 2^{r+s}u\equiv 2^{r+s}\pmod{2^{r+s+1}}$$
so that $2^{r+s}$ is the largest power of 2 dividing the numerator. Likewise $2^s$ is the largest power of 2 dividing the denominator and so $2^{r+s-s}=2^r$ is the largest power of 2 dividing $1+a+\cdots+a^{2^r-1}$.
It follows that $2^m|(1+a+\cdots+a^{k-1})$ if and only if $k$ is of the form $2^rt$ with $t$ odd and $r\ge m$. It follows that the least such value of $k$ for which $x_k=\overline 0$ is $k=2^m$.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks.